# spacing between form fields

Tags: html, css, forms

I have an HTML form element:

```
<form action="doit" id="doit" method="post">
Name <br/>
<input id="name" name="name" type="text" /> <br/>
Phone number <br/>
<input id="phone" name="phone" type="text" /> <br/>
Year <br/>
<input id="year" name="year" type="text" /> <br/>
</form>
```

I would like there to be a little more space between the fields, for example, between the lines

`<input id="name" name="name" type="text" /> <br/>` and 
`Phone number <br/>`,

and also between

`<input id="phone" name="phone" type="text" /> <br/>` and `Year <br/>`.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I would wrap your rows in labels

```
<form action="doit" id="doit" method="post">
    <label>
        Name
        <input id="name" name="name" type="text" />
    </label>
    <label>
        Phone number
        <input id="phone" name="phone" type="text" />
    </label>
    <label>
        Year
        <input id="year" name="year" type="text" />
    </label>
</form>
```

And use

```
label, input {
    display: block;
}

label {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

Don't use `br`s for spacing!

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/D8W2Q/

Comment: Also use <label for="name"> for better user experience and screen reader.So that if user click label, cursor automatically focus on respective input element.

Answer (score 18):

In your CSS file:

```
input { margin-bottom: 10px; }
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple `&nbsp`; between input fields would do the job easily...

Answer (score -3):

```
  <form>     
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="nameLabel">Name</label>
                <input id="name" name="name" class="form-control" type="text" /> 
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="PhoneLabel">Phone</label>
                <input id="phone" name="phone" class="form-control" type="text" /> 
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="yearLabel">Year</label>
                <input id="year" name="year" class="form-control" type="text" />
            </div>
        </form>
```

Comment: Inline style repeated on every div + keep the <br>s, seriously?